# How to make a dictionary from a txt file in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I need to make dictionary from this text

```
Daniel, 2
20, slow, card
3, quick, card
30, slow, cash
Katka, 1.5
13, slow, cash
24, normal, card
```

And I need to get answer like this:

```py
{
  ('Daniel', 2.0): [
    (20, 'slow', 'card'), 
    (3, 'quick', 'card'), 
    (30, 'slow', 'cash')
  ], 
  ('Katka', 1.5): [
    (13, 'slow', 'cash'), 
    (24, 'normal', 'card')
  ]
}
```

**But I can't get how can I make double key (with the name of cashier and float number)**
Please help and sorry for sh*tposting maybe, but that's my first post on so. Thanks a lot

Comment: Text is given in a dotted list like that?

Comment: no, its just a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code:**

```py
import re

text = """Daniel, 2
20, slow, card
3, quick, card
30, slow, cash
Katka, 1.5
13, slow, cash
24, normal, card"""

d, cur_key = dict(), tuple()

for line in text.split("\n"):
    if re.match("^[A-Z]", line):
        name, val = line.split(", ")
        cur_key = (name, float(val))
        d[cur_key] = []
    elif re.match("^[0-9]", line):
        a, b, c = line.split(", ")
        d[cur_key].append((int(a), b, c))

print(d)
```

**Explanation:**

We split the text by `\n` and iterate through lines by checking if the corresponding line represents user info (ex. "Daniel, 2") or its data (ex. "20, slow, card"). We check this using regular expressions: `^[A-Z]` and `^[0-9]`

```
^[A-Z] => text starts with letters A to Z 
^[0-9] => text starts with numbers 0 to 9
```

If the line contains user info, then we convert it to `tuple` and set it as the current dictionary key in `cur_key` and create key with empty list in `d`

If the line contains data, then we append our converted `tuple` to our dictionary `d` inside `cur_key`

Else, we skip the line and continue iteration

**Output:**

```
{('Daniel', 2.0): [(20, 'slow', 'card'), (3, 'quick', 'card'), (30, 'slow', 'cash')], ('Katka', 1.5): [(13, 'slow', 'cash'), (24, 'normal', 'card')]}
```

Comment: This answer does not explain why it works or what conceptual information the OP was missing. How can one learn from it?

Comment: @SethMMorton Hey, thanks for mentioning it. I have added an explanation)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "double key"; remember that anything (that we can compute a hash for) can be a key in dictionary. In this case, you want to use a tuple (consisting of the name and number) as the key, e.g:

```py
cashier = 'Daniel'
x = 2.0
key = (cashier, x)
data[key] = daniels_data
```

or, equivalently

```py
data[(cashier, x)] = daniels_data
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Based on Mkael's guidance, the next thing you might want to try is constructing a loop that reads lines from your and file and builds a dictionary with keys (tuples) from the lines that start with a name, and values (lists of tuples) from the other lines.